# X-editable SetValue not working

Tags: jquery, x-editable, setvalue

Actually I have implemented a feature of sorting of `li` elements with inline editable functionality. User can edit position value of a `li` element to which he wants to swap itself with another `li` element.

After swapping of 2 `li` elements, after applying x-editable first time I suppose when I am swapping 2nd positioned `li` to 4th position `li` they get swapped. But now if I reswap 2nd `li` to 4th `li` then editable function is not being applied. Because its editable value is not being changes as per new position.. Here I have tried to set that with

```
$(div).editable('setValue','new value here',true);
```

Please reply if any one can help..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Looks like you have provided somewhat too little context. Could you show the code so that we can reproduce the described behaviour?

Comment: I've got the same issue. `$('#store-editible-url').editable('setValue',"foo");` just doesn't want to update the value. It updates with the value they entered, but not the value I'm passing to it

Comment: @AndrewNewby, were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @dariru mmm I can't remember to be honest :) It was a long time ago